# Multi level REST API on cake php

Tags: cakephp, rest, multi-level

I'm new to cakephp. I'm using the 2.0.5 release, according it looks like rails on a large bunch of points it is pretty easy to get things done.

I'm currently using it to build an REST api for a game. It is easy to build an REST controller, but can't find a way to get nested ressources.

I mean in rails it is easy like hell to get something like this : controller1/id/controller2/id.

I have an hard time to find a way to do this in cakephp. The mapresources method don't seem to support multilevel rest api. Am i wrong?

How can i do a multi level rest API in cakephp 2?

Comment: Wouldn't you just define a new route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i succeed to build my own generator.

According to the fact you provide an array("parent_controller" => "child_controller").

This way you can generate for superhero  => superpowers

superheros/1/superpowers/ (here with or withouth ids according to your routes.

Args mappeds to method args so function index($superhero_id)

```
function generateNestedResources($array)
    {

        foreach($array as $key=>$value)
        {
            //Index -GET /
             Router::connect('/'.$key.'/:'.$key.'_id/'.$value,
                array('controller' => $value,'action' => 'index','method' => 'GET'),
                array( $key.'_id' => '[0-9]+','pass' => array($key.'_id')));
            // View -GET /id
            Router::connect('/'.$key.'/:'.$key.'_id/'.$value.'/:id',
                array('controller' => $value,'action' => 'view','method' => 'GET'),
                array('id' => '[0-9]+', $key.'_id' => '[0-9]+','pass' => array($key.'_id','id')));

            //add -POST/
             Router::connect('/'.$key.'/:'.$key.'_id/'.$value,
                array('controller' => $value,'action' => 'add','method' => 'POST'),
                array( $key.'_id' => '[0-9]+','pass' => array($key.'_id')));
            //edit -PUT/ID
             Router::connect('/'.$key.'/:'.$key.'_id/'.$value.'/:id',
                array('controller' => $value,'action' => 'edit','method' => 'PUT'),
                array('id' => '[0-9]+', $key.'_id' => '[0-9]+','pass' => array($key.'_id','id')));

            //delete -DELEte /ID
             Router::connect('/'.$key.'/:'.$key.'_id/'.$value.'/:id',
                array('controller' => $value,'action' => 'delete','method' => 'DELETE'),
                array('id' => '[0-9]+', $key.'_id' => '[0-9]+','pass' => array($key.'_id','id')));

        }

    }
```